# Post gives Request Body as nil in Kitura

Tags: swift, server-side, kitura

I tried posting a request to my localhost with a json body from REST CLIENT & POSTMAN and also from terminal. But always the request.body is nil. Using package : .Package(url: "https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure that you have added the BodyParser middleware to your routes. For example:

```
let router = Router()

router.all(middleware: BodyParser())
```

Shmuel Kallner

Comment: Thanks a lot. My syntax was wrong. I had used     router.all("*",middleware: BodyParser())